# IMPORT XML Question, "imported content is empty" error

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to extract the APN and Lot Size information from this site, I cannot find a way to do it. I get the error: "imported content is empty".

My formula is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://scoutred.com/maps/parcels/924366/@32.7714,-117.1731,17.00?address_id=228931","//*[@id='parcel']")
```

What is the error?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the page of your URL, it seems that your expected values are shown by Javascript. In this case, unfortunately, IMPORTXML cannot be used. But, fortunately, when I checked the page, I found that the API for retrieving your expected values. So, in this case, how about the following answer? In this answer, Google Apps Script is used.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  url = `https://scoutred.com/api/parcels/${url.split("/")[5]}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const { lotSizeSF, lotSizeAcres, permits: { 0: { apnFmt } } } = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  return [[lotSizeSF, lotSizeAcres, apnFmt]];
}
```

When you can put only the value of `924366`, you can also use the following sample script.

```js
function SAMPLE(id) {
  url = `https://scoutred.com/api/parcels/${id}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const { lotSizeSF, lotSizeAcres, permits: { 0: { apnFmt } } } = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  return [[lotSizeSF, lotSizeAcres, apnFmt]];
}
```

In this case, `=SAMPLE("924366")` can be used.

#### Testing:

When you use the above 1st sample script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("https://scoutred.com/maps/parcels/924366/@32.7714,-117.1731,17.00?address_id=228931")` into a cell. By this, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- In the current stage, the above sample script can be used. But, when the specification is changed at the server side, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)